# Flutter work on a project from Mac and windows

Tags: windows, macos, flutter, dart

Is it possible to work on a flutter project from Mac and Windows at the same time ?

Same time in the sense, work on Mac and test with iOS. later access the folder from windows and test windows device without copying the project folder? may be by storing project on a shared space ?

Any Help will be highly appreciated as I'm trying to develop an app that should work on iOS,android and Windows.

Comment: Use version control for that like github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write code (on Windows or MacOS) and push it to GitHub
2. Clone your app (on MacOS or Windows)

   `$` git clone https://github.com/myUserId/myApp.git

   `$` cd myApp
3. Make sure You've downloaded the app's dependencies

   `$` flutter pub get
4. [Modify the iOS version of the app as necessary]
5. Build it (`$ flutter build ios`) or run it (`$ flutter run`)!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem there. If from your Windows and MacOS device you can both access the project (on a shared folder for exemple) you should have any problem running Flutter on both of your devices.

You may want to use something more "easier" like a GitHub project where you only have to `git pull` the changes made.